# Finding Maclaurin-series of integral

Tags: calculus

I wish to find the Maclaurin-series for the function $$L(x) = \int_0^x \cos(t^2)\space dt$$

> **Alternative 1**
>
> Set $f(t) = \cos(t)$. We have that $f'(t) = -\sin(t)$, $f''(t) = -\cos(t)$ and $f^{(3)}(t) = \sin(t)$. Setting $t = 0$, we find that the pattern $1, 0, -1, 0$ repeats itself indefinitely. The Maclaurin-series for $\cos(t)$ is therefore $P(t) = 1 - t^2/2! + t^4/4! ...$, and $P(t^2) = 1 - t^4/2! + t^8/4!...$
>
> Therefore we have $$L(x) = \int_0^t (1 - t^4/2! + t^8/4!...)\space dt = x - x^5/(5\cdot2!) + x^9/(9\cdot4!)... = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{4n+1}}{(4n+1)(2n)!}$$

The answer above is correct. I dislike solving tasks that way unless I absolutely have to, and I attempted the following (more tiresome) method several times until I gave up on it and used the simplification above:

> **Alternative 2**
>
> Set $f(t) = \cos(t^2)$. Computing the first few derivatives, we have that
>
> $f'(t) = -2t\sin(t^2)$
>
> $f''(t) = -2\sin(t^2) -4t^2\cos(t^2) = -2(\sin(t^2)+2t^2\cos(t^2))$
>
> $f^{(3)}(t) = -2(2t\cos(t^2)+4t\cos(t^2)-4t^3\sin(t^2)) = 8t^3\sin(t^2)-12t\cos(t^2)$
>
> It follows that $f^{4}(0) = -12$. So we have a starting pattern like $1, 0, 0, 0, -12, 0 , 0, 0, C$

It looks rather hopeless, but I am unable to see how this can simply be used to find the representation. Should I acccept that the first alternative is superior, or is there a simple method I am missing in Alternative 2?

Comment: This is a [Fresnel integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral).

Comment: While this did not answer my question: thanks! I found this very interesting (and I am disappointed that the text does not give information like that when giving exercises as to encourage the reader further into the subject.)